# Lucidworks Hadoop Solr- Split text into paragraphs

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucidworks, bigdata

I am using this project :https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr and
I am trying to split some text into paragraphs and search for words into them. But as return i take the line that the word is in. Is it possible to do something like that?

I am using this :

```
hadoop jar solr-hadoop-job-2.2.5.jar com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob 
-Dlww.commit.on.close=true 
-Dcom.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.RegexIngestMapper.regex="(?sm)^.*?\.\s*$"  
-Dcom.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.RegexIngestMapper.groups_to_fields=0=match1_ss
-cls com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.RegexIngestMapper -c test2 -i /usr/local/hadoop/input
-s http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr -of com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat
```